# Using static to create an immutable object

Tags: object-oriented, immutability, static-methods

I was reading on this [software engineering page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95499/object-oriented-class-design?rq=1) about the use of `static` methods. However, I'm confused, and maybe it's about the context in which it talks about `static`. The idea is, that static is really bad for testing and shouldn't be used.

When creating immutable class, sometimes the constructor is private and a static factory is used to create the object. Even Java's own [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) supports the use of a factory when creating immutable objects.

> A more sophisticated approach is to make the constructor private and
>   construct instances in factory methods

Comment: Beware dogmatism.

Comment: You should probably edit this and make the question more explicit - while I am pretty sure I know what you are asking here, it is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you are making an immutable DTO, where you simply bundle up a bunch of properties and that's it, such as your example, then just use a public constructor.

Factories are for situations where object construction is complicated, expensive, where you return different types based on the input values, or other "logic intensive" situations. Simply storing a handful of values is not one of those situations.

Comment: See my edit, I think "where you return different types based on the input values" is what I do in my example.

Comment: @S.R.: that's not what I'm seeing. I don't see anything besides "Weapon" being returned.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is, that static is really bad for testing and shouldn't be used.

Yes static code makes unit testing harder (sometime impossible). But I would not go as far as saying *`static` should not be used*. There are some cases where static methods are fine to use.

Here is why it makes testing harder. Consider this code you have in your question:

```
public static Weapon Sword(String name, damage){
    return new Weapon(name, damages);
}
```

Wherever that code is written is permanently coupled to `Weapon`. Without the `Weapon` class, no one can compile the above code. No one can substitute a mock object instead of `Weapon` to test the class where this code appears.

The easiest rule to remember is that as soon as you you use `new` keyword to instantiate an object of class `X`, you have made your class coupled to `X` and unit testing will be not be possible unless you were to change the code in class `X` (but that would be a very odd unit test because you would need to change the code in class `X` back to the real code before sending it to production). Please read more [here](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) about unit testing static code.

Comment: Would it then be better then to make the constructor public and use that for creating objects? In my case make the weapon constructor public?

Comment: @S.R. no that would not be better. You can leave it as is but if you are interested in why static code is harder to unit test then read the article I referred in my answer. Then try to unit test your code and you will run into obstacles and you will then clearly understand why static code is harder to test. It is really hard to explain this without a lengthy article or discussion. Also, if someone does not fully understand unit testing and mocking, then it further complicates the explanation. Is there a specific part you do not understand and perhaps I can try and explain that part?

Comment: I'm still learning, so for you to explain, is going take some time and go beyond the scope of the question. For example, If I wanted to keep weapon immutable, but have different types, so sword and gun, I could still keep the constructor private and use a static factory to return those types, correct?

Comment: Let me edit my question

Comment: @S.R. You do not need a factory to create immutable objects. I suggest you throw away the factory and only use it if you ever need it. Using design patterns can (often it does) complicate your code. Only use it if you have a need. I honestly do not think you need it in this case. Please do a quick read of Factory design pattern.

Comment: Downvoting this answer as it is fundamentally a flawed answer. Static functions only make testing harder if they are non-deterministic and/or have side effects. The argument in the link provided that "Unit-testing assumes that I can instantiate a piece of my application in isolation" is complete nonsense: unit testing is simply testing parts of the code in isolation. If a static method is pure (is deterministic and has no side effects) then it is as good a candidate for unit testing as one can get as it inherently executes in isolation.

Comment: Clearly the factory methods in the question call `new`, they have side effects. However, that side effect is identical to just calling a public constructor, so they are no more difficult to test than the latter.

Comment: @DavidArno - Still learning here, so what are the side effects of using `new`? How would I create a new Weapon without using `new`?

Comment: @S.R., the side-effects of using `new` are that it impacts upon the heap and thus potentially the GC. But upon reflection I'm being needlessly pedantic. So I'd suggest ignoring that statement from me :)

Comment: @DavidArno - how would you create a new object if not with the `new` keyword?

Comment: @DavidArno: If you have any class that utilizes those pure static functions, some people will whine that your unit test is now an integration test.

Comment: @whatsisname I know. I just let whine and ignore them. :)

Comment: @S.R., well you can't. But a slightly different question, "how would you supply an object without `new`?", then the answer would be, eg use an object pool, or with C# for example, you could use stack based structs to avoid hitting the heap. But as I said previously, that's all pointless pendanticism, so just ignore what I said ;)

Comment: @S.R. You can create a new object without `new` using IoC container (underneath it will call new at some point but your code is not tied to it.) This will be done at the composition root level and its okay if at that level you commit to concrete implementation. I think you are digging too deep into this and without getting your hands dirty and actually writing code and then writing unit tests or TDD, it will be really hard for you to grasp these topics. Just write some unit tests and you will see it for yourself.

Comment: `static` code doesn't automatically make unit testing harder. Static *dependencies* do in some cases, in languages where you can't stub out anything but instances (e.g., Java and C#). However, even in those languages, static code that can be unit tested purely via input and output is not more difficult to test, and static method calls that are best regarded as implementation details that the unit test should not care about also don't increase the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that static instances (or static functions that have some state associated with them) are bad comes from the argument that says that having those is the same as having *global* variables (global state - see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109) for more info on why *that's* bad).

A constructor is just a special kind of function - it's not something that manipulates global state in this sense. You don't need to have a reference to an instance to call it (even in prototype-based languages), so in a way, you can think of it as being static, or behaving as if it's static. From that point of view, having a static factory method is no different. So the global state argument doesn't apply here.

Comment: So, it's fine to use a static method as a way of creating and returning an immutable object? As stated in the JavaDocs

Comment: IMO - yes. As far as I'm aware, it's a relatively common thing to do. Also, there's an advantage of being able to give a more meaningful name to your static factory method (or methods). Now, as the JavaDocs say, this is one way to prevent inheritance, and it's one that generalizes fairly well to other languages. I wouldn't necessarily agree that it's "a more sophisticated approach" compared to marking the class *final* (or *sealed*, the C# equivalent).

Comment: @S.R.: no, it's not fine. It'll compile and execute, but it violates the Principle of least astonishment. If you want to create an object, you should normally use `new`.

Comment: @S.R. (C.C. @whatsisname): For the record, I actually agree with whatsisname when it comes to *when* you should use constructors vs factory methods (Principle of least astonishment). My answer and my previous comment were made under the assumption that you are asking *specifically* if the reasoning behind the advice to avoid static (global) methods/state applies to static factory methods, as I get the impression that you are looking to understand the *"why"* behind it all.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - You read my question, I meant with regards to static factory methods. I wanted to know the why